# Need to reach code behind clicking on a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I need to reach a code behind a function when I click on a hyperlink... very uncommon. I did put my hyperlinks into a div, that div has a onclick event that should (I think it does but i'm not sure) reach a javascript function witch is into the same .ascx file i'm working on. That javascript function make another invisible button trigger IS event that has a code behind a function. All that because div and hyperlink cannot have codebehind functions ? Anyway here is the code :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MenuPrincipal.ascx.cs"     Inherits="BaseApplication.Composant.MenuPrincipal"  %>


<asp:Button style="position:absolute; left:100%;" Visible="false"  runat="server" ID="fakebtn" OnClick="fromInside" />

<div id="divi" onclick="DivClick();"> CLICKING HERE SHOULD MAKE ME REACH CODE BEHIND


<% // lots of conditionals hyperlinks %>


 <% if(BLL.FakeBD.ObtenirDroitAccesStatic(login) < 1) { %>

 <asp:HyperLink  ID="hlinkAccueil" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/">Accueil</asp:HyperLink>
<% }%>


  <% // end of :lots of conditionals hyperlinks %>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function DivClick()
{
    var btn = $('fakebtn');
    btn.click();

}
```

Comment: Why not a LinkButton?

Comment: because there is a lot of hyperlinks into the div and they all need to use the exact same code behind

Comment: Ok i'm going to use that, and put in every single linkButton the OnClick="fromInside"... can't do better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClick="fromInside" ID="hlinkAccueil" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/">Accueil</asp:LinkButton>
```

I deleted the rest, it wasen't useful anymore